# Moment format complicated date

Tags: momentjs

I want to format a date to moment "From Now" and localize it. My input is "6/30/2020, 5:58:41 PM".

I tried:

```js
moment.locale('he');
var m = moment("6/30/2020, 5:58:41 PM");
m.fromNow(); // "5 week from now"
console.log(m)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/locale/he.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This looks like it's just a typo?  You're logging `m` to the console, not `m.fromNow()`.

Comment: thank u i understand now